# Authentication in microservice application that has different frameworks/ programming language

Tags: node.js, django, authentication, microservices, csrf-token

I am a bit confused on how to implement a authentication with a microservice architecture if my microservices use different FW such as node, django, go ... is there a common token type that can be interpreted by all the FW available? CRSF tokens are universal in different FW/programming languages, what about JWT, basic auth is good enough? what is the most recommended approach? get a token store in the front end and for every microservice validate the token before actually doing something? remembering that every MS would be written in different FW and Programming language

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into a universal, platform indenpendant authentication framework consider looking into oauth and maybe the extension OIDC.